# Jackson: Mapping JSON response to multiple beans

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a json which has multiple types. Example:

```
{ 
  "Type1":{"name:":"abc","age":23},
  "Type2":{"count":0, "id":"abcd"}
}
```

This I want to map to to classes "Type1" and "Type2".

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the simplest way is to create a Wrapper Bean

```
public class WrapperBean{
    private Bean1 bean1;
    private Bean2 bean2;
    // getters, setters
}
```

Comment: Although I was looking for a solution where I ask the wrapper to construct beans separately, but this works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try using contructor over load

```
Class MainType () {
  MainType(String name, int age) {
    Type1  type1 = new Type1();
  }

  MainType(int count, String id) {
    Type2  type2 = new Type2();
  }
}
```

.... You Type1 and Type2 class goes here.

Comment: It solves but this doesn't seems an intuitive design to me. What you think? A better solution (which I was looking for) could have been
     Type1 objectType1 = wrapper.readValue(..., Type1.class)
     Type2 objectType2 = wrapper.readValye(..., Type2.class)
Guess it isn't possible :(

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking case where json data is transferred from client to server?

```
@RequestMapping("/performTest.json")
    public @ResponseBody String performTest(@RequestBody List<Object> jsonData){
List<Bean> beanList=new ArrayList<Bean>();        
for(Object obj:jsonData){
                LinkedHashMap<String,Object> map=(LinkedHashMap<String,Object>)obj;

Bean bean=new Bean();
bean.setName(map.get("name"));
bean.setAge(map.get("age"));
beanList.add(bean);
}
```

Please note this is not the best solution but one more way to solve your problem..do update us when you get final approach to solve this problem..

Comment: if we do it like this, then whole purpose of using jackson for easy mapping is dissolved.